# Call to undefined function jetpack_register_genericons()

Tags: wordpress, jetpack

I am using Jetpack on a clients site for statistics collection and today Jetpack threw this error. I have googled around and found that [there is a bug fix](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/changelog/), which was already included in the version that I am using. Otherwise I haven't found any other useful information as to why I am getting this error. Has anyone also come across this?

Comment: Can you link to the bug fix report?

Comment: Maybe publish an answer? So it helps anyone with the same problem...

Comment: @brasofilo i just did below

Comment: Cool, formatted nicely ;)

Answer (score 1):

After doing a stack trace, I found that the function `jetpack_register_genericons()` is actually not defined and is just being fired manually.... when you look at the code you find the following comments right before the function call

```
/**
 * As jetpack_register_genericons is by default fired off a hook,
 * the hook may have already fired by this point.
 * So, let's just trigger it manually.
 */
```

So I just commented it out and the error didn't appear anymore.